# Why does acetic acid (CH3COOH) conduct electricity the worst in comparison to HBr, HCOONa and NaNO3

Tags: aqueous-solution, solutions, ions

Which of the given substances (in an aqueous solution) conducts electricity the worst: $\ce{CH3COOH}$, $\ce{HBr}$, $\ce{HCOONa}$ and $\ce{NaNO3}$?

I've found this assingment included in the 2017 national chemistry exam paper, and the published solution is that the correct answer is $\ce{CH3COOH}$.

I would be very grateful for a thorough explanation behind the science of this assignment. Thank you for the time taken.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HBr, NaNO3 and HCOONa are all fully ionised in aqueous solution so all of their material is available as ions to conduct electricity.
Acetic acid with a pKa of 4.75 is not fully ionised so the solution will be a poorer conductor

Answer (score 1):

It's because acetic acid won't fully ionize in solution, it's a weak acid. Less ionization means less total amount of ions in solution, which implies lower electrical conductivity. The wording of the question is bad IMO however, because it already assumes you are comparing over equal *molar* concentrations of each solution. If the question was about *mass* concentration the analysis would have to be different.